# jQuery Chosen - How to Dynamically Change Options Whilst Retaining Selected Choices

Tags: jquery, json, jquery-chosen

I currently have a page with two dropdowns, one is a `chosen` select input and the other a normal select containing organisations.

When the selected organisation is changed I am trying to dynamically update the options available in the `chosen` select but remember the previously selected choices.

**JS**

```
// when the organisation is changed, re-populate list
$('#cc_list_organisation').change(function() {

    $.ajax({
        type: 'POST',
        url: '/organisation/ajax_find_employees',
        dataType: 'json',
        data: { organisation_id: $('#cc_list_organisation').val() },
        success: function(data) {
            $('#cc_list').empty().append(data.html);


            $('ul.chzn-results').empty();

            var choices = $('.chzn-choices').html(); // save previous choices in variable

            $("#cc_list").trigger("liszt:updated");

            $('.chzn-choices').empty().html(choices); // 

            /*

            // was trying to do it manually but kept getting an error, and then I found the above
            var results = $.parseJSON(data.js);

            response($.map(results, function(item) {

                $('ul.chzn-results').append('<li id="cc_list_chzn_o_' + item.index + '" class="active-result">' + item.name + '</li>');
                }));
            */
        }

    });

    return false;

});
```

**JSON**

```
{
   "html":"\u003Coption value=\"214\"\u003EPerson 1\u003C/option\u003E\u003Coption value=\"367\"\u003EPerson 2\u003C/option\u003E",
   "js":"{ \"index\": 0, \"name\": \"Person1\" }, { \"index\": 1, \"name\": \"Person 2\" }"
}
```